# Configuring Spring's ApplicationContext reference path while running Tomcat thru Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

For my debug setup, when running Tomcat from Eclipse my Spring app's ApplicationContext points to WEB-INF but when Tomcat is run from command line the Application Context points to WEB-INF/classes. So, when running Tomcat from Eclipse I want `applicationContext.getResource("path relative to WEB-INF/classes")` to look for resources relative to WEB-INF/classes rather than WEB-INF. Any clues?

Comment: Which looks more like a setup problem. `WEB-INF/classes` is part of the class path, so if you want to load something from there prefix the resource with `classpath:` instead of trying something else.